# Get a Value for Empty Date in MySQL Date function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following MySQL query

```
SELECT SUM( mc_gross ) AS total, MONTH( transaction_datetime ) AS months 
FROM users_payment 
WHERE 1 AND YEAR( transaction_datetime ) = '2020' 
GROUP BY MONTH( transaction_datetime ) , YEAR( transaction_datetime )
```

the output i get is

```
total month
34.90 2
4.95 3
49.85 4
14.85 5
```

However, i like to see if i can create below output, just from the MySQL query ?

```
total month
0.00 1
34.90 2
4.95 3
49.85 4
14.85 5
 0.00 6
 0.00 7
 0.00 8
 0.00 9
 0.00 10
 0.00 11
 0.00 12
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RIGHT JOIN` against a *table expression* with all 12 values.

For example:

```
select
  coalesce(q.total, 0.0) as total,
  m.n as month
from ( -- your query here
  SELECT SUM( mc_gross ) AS total, MONTH( transaction_datetime ) AS months
  FROM users_payment 
  WHERE 1 AND YEAR( transaction_datetime ) = '2020' 
  GROUP BY MONTH( transaction_datetime ) , YEAR( transaction_datetime )
) q
right join (
  select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 
  union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
  union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
  union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
) m on q.months = m.n
order by m.n
```